# MAC Address changes after dirty shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, networking, hardware, udev

I'm having a strange issue which I originally thought was tied to the fact that I created an Ubuntu system from an image of another.  However, after reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch I am getting the same behaviour.  Basically whenever there is a dirty shutdown (power gets yanked) the MAC address gets set to a new value, and the `/etc/network/interfaces` gets updated with the new address and an incremented `ethX`.  This is causing all kinds of problems and I really have no idea why this is happening.  I've set up many systems just like this one and never had this happen.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit with all updates installed.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the system run in a virtualized environment?

Comment: Nope.  It's running on hardware.

Comment: Can you change the NIC or is it on-board? A changing MAC on power surges could be hardware issue (although a strange one).

Comment: This is a workaround: https://github.com/cubieplayer/Cubian/issues/47

Comment: How many interfaces does it have?

Comment: It only has one.

Comment: What make and kind of ethernet controller is that? Or if it is the on-board one what is Motherboard make and type.

Comment: Motherboard: Intel D2550MUD2 with on board network port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular issue sounds like this bug in Launchpad's bug tracker. Specifically this bug, titled: [Ethernet device's MAC address changes (causing its device number to increase by one each time)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/153727). This is an old bug and there are several workarounds within this ticket as well as these workarounds that I found on this Github page, titled: [Fix Ethernet MAC address](https://github.com/cubieplayer/Cubian/issues/47).

On the surface this sounds like a potential hardware issue, but given the evidence in the Launchpad ticket I'd be very suspicious of Ubuntu as well. To break the tie I would suggest an completely different distro, for no other reason than to confirm or eliminate the likelihood that the issue lies with the hardware or the software.

Comment: Thanks for putting your time in on this.  This helps a lot.

Comment: @Zobal - you're welcome, thanks for all the Q's. Good stuff!!